# startActivity from BroadcastReceiver Button Views on Activity don't show up

Tags: android

I start my activity alarmAlert.class from onReceive().
The activity was started .
There three buttons and two TextViews on my activity.
when the activity started ,Textviews always show up,
but the buttons not always show up.

I start the activity from my MainActivity ,all the views work
perfect

Anything I can do .
thanks

I got something.
If my App is not running in background (click menu button,remove the app from list)
the activity started from onReceive() , buttons will not show up.
if the App still run in background ,everything is perfect .

my onReceive code:

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int id = intent.getIntExtra("id", -1);

    try{
    Intent alertIntent=new Intent();
    alertIntent.setClass(context, AlarmAlert.class);
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("id", id);
    alertIntent.putExtras(bundle);
    alertIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION);
    context.startActivity(alertIntent);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        AlarmGloble.writeLog(context,"AlarmReceiver:"+e.toString());
    }
```

part of my AlarmAlert code

```
        @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("AA","onCreate");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.alarm_alert);

    AlarmGloble.dbHelper=new DBHelper(this,AlarmGloble.DB_NAME,AlarmGloble.DB_VERSION);
    AlarmGloble.dbLib=new DataBaseLib(AlarmGloble.dbHelper);

    settingFromId();

    findViews();
    setListener();
    updateView();
    mVibrator=(Vibrator)getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE); 

    setSystemVolume(0);

    //play mp3 by Handler
    mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(PLAY));


}

    private void updateView(){
    TextView textViewSnooze=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.alarm_alertTextViewSnooze);
    if (mp3Test){
        textViewSnooze.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        spinnerSnooze.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        buttonClose.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        buttonEdit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        textViewSnooze.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        spinnerSnooze.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonClose.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if(alarmRept<=0){           
            textViewSnooze.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            spinnerSnooze.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            textViewSnooze.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            spinnerSnooze.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (alarmReptCount<alarmReptTimes)
                if (alarmKind==0)
                    mMessage=mMessage+"\n"+"next alarm :"+mClockSnooze[alarmRept]+" ";
                else
                    mMessage=mMessage+"\n"+"next alarm:"+AlarmGloble.rept[alarmRept]+" ";

        }

    }

    textViewMessage.setText(mMessage);


    if(mMp3.equals(AlarmGloble.RANDOM)){
        File file=new File(AlarmGloble.ROOT_MUSIC);
        RandomMp3 rm=new RandomMp3(file);
        if (rm.getCount()>0)
            mMp3=rm.getFile();
        else
            mMp3="";

    }
    else {
        if(mMp3.equals(AlarmGloble.DEFAULT)){
            mMp3=getDefaultMP3();
        }
        else{
            String[] s=mMp3.split("/");
            textViewSongName.setText(s[s.length-1]);
        }
    }

    if (mMp3.equals("")){
        textViewSongName.setText(mMp3);
    }
    else {
        String[] s=mMp3.split("/");
        textViewSongName.setText(s[s.length-1]);
    }
    (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.alarm_alertLinearLayoutButtons);
    linearLayoutButtons.requestFocus();
}
```

here is alarm_alert.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/linearLayoutAlarmAlert" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/alarm_alertLinearLayoutButtons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/alarm_alertButtonClose"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnClose" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/alarm_alertButtonEdit"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnEdit"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/alarm_alertButtonDismiss"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnExit"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alarm_alertTextViewSnooze"
        style="@style/RedLeft17sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/snooze" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/alarm_alertSpinnerSnooze"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/alarm_alertTextViewMessage"
    style="@style/YellowLeft17sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btnClose" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/alarm_alertTextViewSongName"
    style="@style/YellowLeft17sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:text="@string/btnClose" />    
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Where you initializing the value of 'mp3Test'

Comment: in the function settingFromId();

Comment: I got something. If my App is not running in background (click menu button,remove the app from list) the activity started from onReceive() , buttons will not show up. if the App still run in background ,everything is perfect .

Answer (score 0):

I can only see 2 buttons buttonClose and buttonEdit in the AlarmAlert Activity, so i'm assuming the 3 buttons that aren't showing are in alarm_alertLinearLayoutButtons.xml which should be reused in alarm_alert.xml as such

```
<include layout="@layout/alarm_alertLinearLayoutButtons"/>
```

Ref: http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

I can't see anything wrong with this except for the last couple of lines.
linearLayoutButtons isn't set.

```
linearLayoutButtons = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.alarm_alertLinearLayoutButtons);
linearLayoutButtons.requestFocus();
```

Comment: I post my alarm_alert.xml, linearLayoutButtons is the linearlayout contain 3 buttons. linearLayoutButtons.requestFocus(); that I tried to get focus to see if the buttons will show up ..

Comment: One thing i noticed is that you're doing a Log.d("AA","onCreate"); before super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); , it is better to let the super class do its work before you do anything. Try moving the log after calling super.

Ref: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html
"Note: Your implementation of these lifecycle methods must always call the superclass implementation before doing any work, as shown in the examples above."